# 'make install' problem

Tags: command-line, make

I am new to ubuntu. So I tired to install a software by typing the 'make install'. this error is occurred. Please help me.

```
cd src && make CC='gcc' CPPFLAGS='' DEFS='-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSYSTEM_WGETRC=\"/usr/bin//etc/wgetrc\" -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/bin//share/locale\"' CFLAGS='-O2 -Wall -Wno-implicit' LDFLAGS='' LIBS='' prefix='/usr/bin/' exec_prefix='/usr/bin/' bindir='/usr/bin//bin' infodir='/usr/bin//info' mandir='/usr/bin//man' manext='1' install.bin
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/praneethpj/wget1.5.3/src'
gcc -O2 -Wall -Wno-implicit  -o wget  cmpt.o connect.o fnmatch.o ftp.o ftp-basic.o ftp-ls.o ftp-opie.o getopt.o headers.o host.o html.o http.o init.o log.o main.o md5.o netrc.o rbuf.o recur.o retr.o url.o utils.o version.o 
/usr/bin/ld: h_errno: TLS definition in //lib/libc.so.6 section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference in ftp.o
//lib/libc.so.6: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [wget] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/praneethpj/wget1.5.3/src'
make: *** [install.bin] Error 2
```

Comment: Please let us know, which software you are trying to install.

Comment: hi, when i install any software this error is showed.after typing the make or make install command

Comment: that is my point, install from software center. Use make stuff only when the software is not present.

Comment: i think ,I solved this.I installed the perl.and I update the Ubuntu OS.it is done

Comment: still my point is valid. Avoid install from source as much as possible. Every time there is a breaking changes to any of it's dependency , you installation will break and you have to compile again.

Comment: @PraneethPj Since you've solved your problem, please [post your own solution as an answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) (if you cannot do so now, you'll be able to soon).

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install firefox
this is through terminal
if you want to install it via GUI then ubuntu software source is a good Repositories type what ever software you want to install and install,another way is through synaptic package manager for more details on this read http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Software-in-Ubuntu

Comment: problem solved the reason of UBUNTU version. i changed the Ubuntu 10.10 to 12.10

Answer (score 0):

To install a software using the source code, as you're trying to do, normally requires 3 commands. Following are the steps, you need to follow:

- Move to the directory containing the source code.

```
cp /path/to/source/code
```

- Look for file named `README` or `INSTALL`. The file, if present, would probably contain install instructions.

Otherwise, you can also look at the website from where you downloaded the source to get the information.

- If you don't want to do so, which I do recommend doing, run the following commands:

```
    ./configure
    make
    sudo make install
```

- You might get error at `./configure`, which would mean that either `configure` file is not present, in which case you should read the installation instructions, or there can be some dependencies which need to be installed first.

Or, of course, they can be just some warnings that won't mean much depending on the use case.

Comment: I was followed this steps.but it is happend.the error showed after typing the 'make' or 'make install' command